# jQuery plugin's $ collides with jQuery's $

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 js files, call them *myJavascript.js*, *myPlugin.js* and the *jQuery* libary.

The files themselves are relatively long, so I try to convey the issue without copying the entire scripts.

 
In the html file using them, I've included the js files in the following order:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/myPlugin.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/myJavascript.js"></script>
```

I've written the plugin in the following structure:
***myPlugin.js :***

```
(function ($) {
    local variables...

    //several functions with the form
    $.fn.funcName = function(parameters) { body };

    //several function used internally
    function funcName(parameters) { body }

}(jQuery));
```

In *myJavascript.js*, I'm using only methods defined in the plugin (just like using jQuery methods), and it's working. However, when I tried to invoke a jQuery method (authentic one, not from the plugin) **before** invoking plugin function, I got the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mazeBoard is not a function
```

To give a concrete example:

```
    /* when this block exists, the call to mazeBoard throws the error */
    /* when I remove this block, the call to mazeBoard works perfectly */
    {
        $(function () {
            jQuery("#navigationMenu").load("nav.html");
            loadSettings();
        });
    }
    /********************/
    {
        ...local variables...

        function getSingleGame() {
            ...body...
            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

                //this is some function in myJavascript.js
                var mazeData = makeMazeData(data.Maze, data.Rows, data.Cols);

                //this is call to function from my plugin
                mymaze = $('#mazeCanvas').mazeBoard(mazeData);
                alert('success');
            }).fail(function () {
                alert('error!');
            });
        }
    }
```

Anyone knows what's the problem? If everything seems to be fine, I'll try to add more details.

Comment: Is jQuery.js loaded more than once in page?

Comment: what does nav.html contain? What does loadSettings() actually load? As charlietfi mentions you might be loading another jQuery.js file which will overwrite the old jQuery object and therefore your plugin

Comment: `mazeBoard` is ur plugin ??

Comment: nav.html contains reference to jQuery, why is that a problem?

Comment: because the second version will overwrite the first one that the plugin is referenced to